# UIAlertview delegate will crash when setting delegate to self

Tags: xcode, crash, uialertview, exc-bad-access

I have this simple piece of code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contact" message:@"This contact does not exist yet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"  otherButtonTitles:@"Not now", nil];
[alert show];
```

If I set delegate to 'nil', everything is fine. However, if I set delegate to 'self' and add either a clickedButtonAtIndex or didDismissWithButtonIndex delegate, the application crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: did you put the <UIAlertViewDelegate> in your .h?

Comment: Please check in your .h file you have #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

Comment: yes, have <UIAlertViewDelegate> in the header

Comment: when do your app crashes? on show or on click?

Comment: when I click on either button

Comment: Did u implement the function   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not set the alertView delegate method.

First set the alertView delegate protocol in .h file.

```
     @interface MainViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Then implement this method, it will work fine

```
  -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
   switch (buttonIndex)
  {
    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that your object (self) doesn't exists anymore! but the alertview try to access it, so your get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Check if your delegate object (self) is alive!

Comment: That seems to be a good point. But according to the iOS flow, if I call a class containing an alert, iOs will indeed display the alert and immediately return to the caller, so in fact, self will never exist with the alert. Can I delegate to the caller?

Comment: the caller is your delegate!

Comment: I have put the 'clickedButtonAtIndex in the calling class but it is never called (crash does not occur anymore at least). I have even put a didPresentAlertView in the caller but it is also never called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to my flow. I have a class calling a URL. the Viewcontroller did in fact finish long before the response came form the server. I therefore had to implement an NSRunLoop in the caller in order to wait for the server communication to finish. Based on some ExitCode form the called routine, I could then only display an alert and get the delegate to handle the pressed button. Thanks anyway to Chakalaka for putting me on the track.